# Installing SSL in Amazon Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-lightsail

So my team just moved my website from another host to Amazon Lighsail (Wordpress) on the previous host it's already secure (HTTPS), my team also already upload my own cert using Certificate Manager but how to connect it to the Lightsail ?

PS : we already ask the support there, but they only give me the documentation how to use load balancer, ignoring that we already said our own cert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my own cert using Certificate Manager but how to connect it to the Lightsail ?

You **can't use AWS ACM SSL certificates on instances**. They can be only used on load balancers, CloudFront distribution and API Gateway. It does not matter that it is imported cert or not.

To use your own SSL cert, you have to setup your Lightsail instance yourself, without ACM. Usually it is done by using **nginx as a reverse-proxy** in front of your application and manually configuring it to use your SSL certificate. ACM is not involved in this process. Its fully manual setup on your behalf.

Comment: do you have documentation or tutorial for that? i tried to upload my cert to my instance and then change the apache setting, but there's no change in the website (still not secure)

Comment: @GoldenBoy The settings depend on your operating system, web server. There is no one-solution for all possible configurations. You have to google solutions that match your setup. The alternative is to use ALB infront of your instance. SSL can be setup effortless using ACM in that case.

Comment: can install own SSL in lightsail Windows Instance? if yes then after install https not working in site so any other setting required in lightsail?

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma I would suggest to make a proper question dedicated to your issue.

Comment: yes i got solution, problem is aws lightsail have own firewall so you need to open 443 in aws firewall in lightsail as well as in windwos server instance.  There is no proper detrails documents for Widnwos instance